# PHP/MySQL: Better way to write SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a better way to write this query?

startimg point: index.php?IDGruppo=25,48,47&IDFamiglia=845,587,215,444

now i explode IDGruppo and IDFamiglia and build query like:

there is a best way?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalogo_prodotti cp, catalogo_prodotti_attributi cpa WHERE cp.IDProdotto = cpa.IDProdotto ";

if($IDGruppo || $IDVarianti){

    $sql .= "AND ";

    foreach($idg as $v)
    {

    if($IDVarianti){
        $i = 1;
        foreach($idv as $c)
        {
        $sql .= "cp.IDGruppo = '". $v ."' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '".$c."' AND cp.Cancellato = '0' AND cp.Acquistabile = '1' ";

        if($IDTaglia)
         $sql .= "AND cpa.IDFiltro_Taglia = '".$IDTaglia."' ";

        if($IDTessuto)
         $sql .= "AND cp.Key_IT LIKE '%".$IDTessuto."%' ";

        if ( count($idv) != $i ){
         $sql .= "OR ";

         }
        $i++;
        }

    } else {

    $sql .= "cp.IDGruppo = '". $v ."' AND cp.Cancellato = '0' AND cp.Acquistabile = '1' ";

    }
     if ( count($idg) != $j )
     $sql .= "OR ";
     $j++;
    }

}

$sql .= "GROUP BY cp.IDProdotto LIMIT $offset, ".$this->ipp." ";

if($orderBY)
$sql .= "ORDER BY '".$orderBY."'";
```

Comment: There's definitely a better way, I'm just not sure what it is.... ^_^

Comment: Maybe you can factorize several conditions...
Is there a logic behind this query or is this "random" conditions?

Comment: It would help having the table structures. Also try indenting your SQL to make it more readable.

Comment: dear lord. some brackets would help in the first place.

Comment: I assume this functions correctly, as there are no brackets it runs off the order of precedence for OR and AND, but that isn't at all easy to read from this statement.

Comment: I had a nightmare like this once.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalogo_prodotti cp
JOIN catalogo_prodotti_attributi cpa ON cp.IDProdotto = cpa.IDProdotto 
 AND cp.Acquistabile = '1' AND AND cp.Cancellato = '0'
WHERE
cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '121' 
OR cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '123'  
OR cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '159'
OR cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '179' 
OR cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '121'
OR cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '123'
OR cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '159' 
OR cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '179'
OR cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '121'
OR cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '123' 
OR cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '159'
OR cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '179'

GROUP BY cp.IDProdotto LIMIT 0, 40
```

Or possibly:

EDIT - Added Brackets

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalogo_prodotti cp
JOIN catalogo_prodotti_attributi cpa ON cp.IDProdotto = cpa.IDProdotto 
    AND cp.Acquistabile = '1' AND AND cp.Cancellato = '0'
WHERE
(cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia IN ('121','123','159','179'))
OR (cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia IN ('121','123','159','179'))
OR (cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia IN ('121','123','159','179'))

GROUP BY cp.IDProdotto LIMIT 0, 40
```

Comment: If the IDs found in the IN clauses are from other tables in the DB, you can also `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...)` to filter from the set(s) subselected from these tables.

Answer (score 2):

This replaces a lot of your `OR` clauses with a couple of `IN` clauses.

```
SELECT * FROM catalogo_prodotti cp, catalogo_prodotti_attributi cpa 
WHERE cp.IDProdotto = cpa.IDProdotto 
AND cp.IDGruppo IN (29, 30, 33) 
AND cp.IDFamiglia IN (121, 123, 159, 179)
AND cp.Cancellato = '0' 
AND cp.Acquistabile = '1' 
GROUP BY cp.IDProdotto LIMIT 0, 40
```

Here's some other [examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) of using `IN`, and here's a link to the [MySQL documentation for `IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

From the documentation:

> - `expr IN (value,...)`
>     Returns `1` if `expr` is equal to any of the values in the `IN` list, else returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping the sub-statements with brackets will already help. For example `cp.Cancellato` appears 12 time in the same stamement instead of just once. Try building a logic tree for yourself and then write the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use some brackets, only use columns in your SELECT clause that appear in your GROUP BY (or aggregate functions), use formatting, and eliminate duplications from your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT cp.IDProdotto
FROM catalogo_prodotti cp, catalogo_prodotti_attributi cpa 
WHERE cp.IDProdotto = cpa.IDProdotto 
AND cp.Cancellato = '0' 
AND cp.Acquistabile = '1' 
AND (
     (cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '121')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '123')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '159')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '33' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '179')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '121')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '123')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '159')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '30' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '179')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '121')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '123')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '159')
  OR (cp.IDGruppo = '29' AND cp.IDFamiglia = '179')
)
GROUP BY cp.IDProdotto 
LIMIT 0, 40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalogo_prodotti cp, catalogo_prodotti_attributi cpa 
WHERE cp.IDProdotto = cpa.IDProdotto
AND cp.Acquistabile = '1' 
AND cp.Cancellato = '0' 
AND cp.IDFamiglia IN('121','123','159','179')
AND cp.IDGruppo IN ('33','30','29')
GROUP BY cp.IDProdotto LIMIT 0, 40
```

Answer (score 0):

The query below seems to match your intent, but you should reconsider what you are trying to achieve. MySQL lets you abuse the `GROUP BY` statement and return columns that are not being grouped or aggregated. This means that what particular values get returned for these columns is indeterminate and may come from any one of the matching rows. Is that what you want?

```
SELECT *  
FROM catalogo_prodotti cp 
INNER JOIN catalogo_prodotti_attributi cpa ON cp.IDProdotto = cpa.IDProdotto  
WHERE cp.Acquistabile = '1' 
    AND cp.Cancellato = '0' 
    AND cp.IDGruppo in ('29', '30', '33')
    AND cp.IDFamiglia in ('121', '123', '159', '179')
GROUP BY cp.IDProdotto 
LIMIT 0, 40
```